# export from Excel to Word takes very long time on MAC

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that exports specific range of cell from Excel to Word. Below you can see the script

```
Sub Export_to_Word_Mac()
Dim filename As String
Dim FolderName As String
Dim Folderstring As String
Dim FilePathName As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim print_area As Range
Dim appWD As Object
Dim wddoc As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim paragraphCount As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

sh.Unprotect
sh.Rows("15:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True

  For Each rng In sh.Range("B17:B26")
        If rng.Value Like "wpisz zakres usług tutaj..." Then
            rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next rng
    
sh.Protect

    FolderName = "Export"
    
    filename = sh.Range("G4") & "_test_" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy_hhmm") & ".docx"

    Folderstring = CreateFolderinMacOffice2016(NameFolder:=FolderName)
    FilePathName = Folderstring & Application.PathSeparator & filename

On Error Resume Next
   Set appWD = GetObject(, "Word.application")
    If Err = 429 Then
        Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.application")
        Err.Clear
    End If

    Set wddoc = appWD.Documents.Add
    appWD.Visible = True

    With appWD.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
        .TopMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .LeftMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    End With
    
   'copy range to word
    Set print_area = sh.Range("B1:C27")

    print_area.Copy

    'paste range to Word table
    paragraphCount = wddoc.Content.Paragraphs.Count
    wddoc.Paragraphs(paragraphCount).Range.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    appWD.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    appWD.ActiveDocument.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalTop
   'appWD.Activate
    appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs (FilePathName)

    MsgBox "Plik zostal zapisany jako: " & vbNewLine & filename & vbNewLine & _
    " w nowo stworzonym " & FolderName & " w folderze: " & vbNewLine & "Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/"
    
    appWD.Quit
    
    Set wddoc = Nothing
    Set appWD = Nothing
    
End Sub

Function CreateFolderinMacOffice2016(NameFolder As String) As String

    Dim OfficeFolder As String
    Dim PathToFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    OfficeFolder = MacScript("return POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) as string")
    OfficeFolder = Replace(OfficeFolder, "/Desktop", "") & _
        "Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/"

    PathToFolder = OfficeFolder & NameFolder

    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(PathToFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = vbNullString Then
        MkDir PathToFolder
        'MsgBox "You find the new folder in this location :" & PathToFolder
    End If
    CreateFolderinMacOffice2016 = PathToFolder
End Function
```

Unfortunetely, there are a couple of issues:

1. It takes 1,5-2 minutes to export and save the Word file. Could you please help me to optimize the code?
2. I need to open Word application on my Mac to run the script. Otherwise I get Run-time error '9' (Script out of Range). The issue is with this line: `Set appWD = GetObject(, "Word.application")` .
3. The only solution I came up with is to use `.CopyPicture xlScreen` and paste it to Word document. I takes arpund 5 second create Word file, however the content is not editable and it is saved as image.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Keep using Copy but optimize VBA execution

There are many options to improve speed execution in Excel VBA (see [this articles](https://analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/) for more details), but the most useful when copy-pasting is certainly to set :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

However, since you are pasting in Word, you'd have to do the same this for the Word Application to get the maximum speed improvement:

```
appWD.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Note: Make sure to reset `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of your code.

---

### Option 2 : Use an array to transfer the data

If the formatting of the cell in Excel is not necessary, then you could load the content of the cells into an array and write this array to the word document like this:

```
'copy range to word
Dim DataArray() As Variant
DataArray = sh.Range("B1:C27").Value

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim MyWordRange As Object

Set MyRange = appWD.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
appWD.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=MyRange, NumRows:=UBound(DataArray, 1), NumColumns:=UBound(DataArray, 2)
 
'paste range to Word table
For i = 1 To UBound(DataArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(DataArray, 2)
        appWD.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, j).Range.Text = DataArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Note that option 1 and 2 are not necessarily mutually exclusives.

Comment: thanks a lot for your code and suggestion. I tried both options and option 1 doesn't change anything. When running your script from Option 2 I get run-time rror '7' - Out of memory.

Comment: @Adrian – Hum, sometimes the Out of memory can come from a memory leak and restarting Excel can sometime solve this. Have you tried to restart Excel before running Option 2?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work at all, when I click Debug it shows me Set t = Activedocument... line and I get exactly the same error

Comment: @Adrian – I've edited the code in option 2 to avoid using the `t` variable. Hope this solves the issue.